# How to upload edit text field text into server

Tags: java, android

I want to upload image and edit text fields in android by using http connection,image is uploading fine edit text fields are not uploading.please help me.

```
 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
              /* conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_img", fileName); 
               conn.setRequestProperty("email", etemail.getText().toString()); 
               conn.setRequestProperty("phone", etphone.getText().toString()); 
               conn.setRequestProperty("message", etmessage.getText().toString()); 
               conn.setRequestProperty("name",etname.getText().toString()); 
               */



               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_img\";filename=\""
                                         + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\""+ lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(email);
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

Comment: I think this is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759075/creating-file-upload-request-using-java-code

Comment: No my functionality is to upload edit text fields and image like registration form...please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, you want to upload both image and text to server. 
if so refer to below answer. 
Hope this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11590652/2623853